# Does polychromatic light fallows different laws of physics then monochromatic light?

Tags: double-slit-experiment

My understanding is that Yang's double-slit experiment only works with monochromatic light.

- Does it mean that polychromatic light behaves differently then monochromatic light? Or are we simply limited in our measurement tools to detect the same effect with polychromatic light?
- Assuming there are different levels of polychromatic and monochromatic light, how does the interference pattern will be effected going from single to many weave lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spatial period of the fringes on the screen depends on the wavelength of the light, and the distance between the slits.  That means, a distinct pattern for each distinct wavelength.

The different wavelengths *do not* interact with each other. They simply add up. If you use a "white" light source, as Thomas Young did when he originally performed the experiment, you get a pattern that looks like this.

[image: white light interference pattern]

The spacing of the "red" pattern is a bit wider than the spacing of the "blue" pattern because the wavelengths of "red" light are longer than "blue" light.  That's why the outer edges of the fringes are reddish and the inner edges are blueish.  The farther you get from the center fringe, the more the different patterns diverge.

Of course, there's more than just a single "red" wavelength and a single "blue" wavelength making up that picture. There is a continuum of different wavelengths, which gives the pattern an over-all fuzzy appearance.